# Linux date timezone

Tags: linux, date, timezone

I have a question about timezone and the output of the linux `date` command. Is it standard or daylight? `date +%Z` returns `EDT`.

Is there a way to change the timezone returned by `date +%Z` from `EDT` to `EST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone information is stored in the `$TZ` environment variable.

```
TZ=EST date +%Z
```

But why? If you need the string `EST` in the output, just `echo EST` :-)